# pip install pandas in docker using alpine image

Tags: python, pandas, docker, jupyter-notebook, alpine-linux

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install -U scikit-learn
RUN pip install sqlalchemy
RUN pip install PyMySQL
COPY Movie_Recommendation.py /Movie_Recommendation.py
RUN cat /Movie_Recommendation.py
RUN echo "* * * * * echo hello" | crontab - 

RUN echo "* * * * * python3 /Movie_Recommendation.py" | crontab -

CMD ["crond","-f"]
```

Hello I am using this dockerfile to run this file using a cron When I use another image then alpine it works to run the python file but I can't do a cron so, I am using alpine but if I do
RUN pip3 install pandas
or RUN pip3 install -U scikit-learn

When the file runs its doing an error for the pandas installation if I run the dockerfile without the pandas it asks me to install it

Error:

```
#5 88.03   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpck96wudq Check the logs for full command output.
#5 88.03   ----------------------------------------
#5 88.03 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-mfrnv78r/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install pandas]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

Any help would be appreciated!Thank you!

SOLUTION: used this docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-python-machinelearning

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/nickgryg/alpine-pandas/
?

Comment: It is not working its taking too much time to install pandas @SiHa

Comment: That image already has pandas

Comment: looks like it worked I just have a problem with installing scikit-learn ,Thank you for your help!! @SiHa